# How to run a command on startup of sails.js

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

How do you run a command on sails.js? I'm trying to clear a collection before any routes or controllers are executed. However, after models are loaded.

In express it was easy, you could place it in apps.js.  Can't find where it executes in sails.js

Example code:

```
User.update({}, {$set : {'socket': [] } }, {'multi': true}, function(err){ if (err){ console.log(err)} });
```

Comment: FYI, the query you posted won't work as expected, since it's using native MongoDB syntax that the Waterline ORM doesn't understand.  Just do `User.update({}, {'socket': []}).exec(function(err, users){...})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put startup logic in [`/config/bootstrap.js`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/anatomy/myApp/config/bootstrap.js.html).  Just remember to call the callback function at the end so that Sails continues to lift!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in `/config/bootstrap.js` that sets up some users when there is none:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = async function(done) {
  // Set up administrators when there is no users
  if ((await Users.count()) === 0) {
    await Users.createEach([
      { email: "julien@gmail.com", password: "changemeasap" },
      { email: "nada@gmail.com", password: "changemeasap" }
    ]);
  }

  // Don't forget to trigger `done()` when this bootstrap function's logic is finished.
  // (otherwise your server will never lift, since it's waiting on the bootstrap)
  return done();
};
```